# I am trying to filter out some records from an array, but Filter taking affect

Tags: reactjs, filter

Why does the following filter not have an effect?  All the records show from the array.

```
... this.state = {
                assetsid: this.props.match.params.assetsid,
                contacttoassetrelationship: []

     componentDidMount(){
        ContactAssetMasterService.getContactToAssetRelationship().then((res)
=> {
            this.setState({ contacttoassetrelationship: res.data});
        });
        //following line does not work
        this.setState({contacttoassetrelationship: 
    this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.filter(contacttoassetrelationship> => 
      contacttoassetrelationship.assets_assetsid === this.state.assetsid)}); ...
```

---

let result = this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.filter(contacttoassetrelationship>contacttoassetrelationship.assets_assetsid === this.state.assetsid);

gave syntax err: src\components\ListContactAssetMasterComponent.jsx
Line 53:67:  'contacttoassetrelationship' is not defined  no-undef
Line 53:94:  'contacttoassetrelationship' is not defined  no-undef

```
    let result = this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.filter(this.state.contacttoassetrelationship>this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.assets_assetsid === this.state.assetsid);
```

Gave syntax error:
Line 54:13:   'result' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
Line 54:104:  Unexpected mix of '>' and '==='              no-mixed-operators
Line 54:159:  Unexpected mix of '>' and '==='              no-mixed-operatorslet result = this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.filter(contacttoassetrelationship>contacttoassetrelationship.assets_assetsid === this.state.assetsid);

gave syntax err: src\components\ListContactAssetMasterComponent.jsx
Line 53:67:  'contacttoassetrelationship' is not defined  no-undef
Line 53:94:  'contacttoassetrelationship' is not defined  no-undef

```
    let result = this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.filter(this.state.contacttoassetrelationship>this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.assets_assetsid === this.state.assetsid);
```

Gave syntax error:
Line 54:13:   'result' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
Line 54:104:  Unexpected mix of '>' and '==='              no-mixed-operators
Line 54:159:  Unexpected mix of '>' and '==='              no-mixed-operators

Comment: Reread your question and realised that my answer were a bit of.

Comment: What happens if you write this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.filter(c => c.assets_assetsid === this.state.assetsid)});?

Comment: @iikkoo Found my error !  Extra });  before the filter statement.  I do not think it ever was executing.  You can see it in the  original post. Following works !
componentDidMount(){
        ContactAssetMasterService.getContactToAssetRelationship().then((res) => {
            this.setState({ contacttoassetrelationship: res.data});
        this.setState({contacttoassetrelationship: this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.filter(contacttoassetrelationship => contacttoassetrelationship.assets_assetsid === this.props.match.params.assetsid)});
    });

Answer (score 0):

Found my error ! Extra }); before the filter statement. I do not think it ever was executing. You can see it in the original post. Following works !
...

> componentDidMount(){
> ContactAssetMasterService.getContactToAssetRelationship().then((res)
> => { this.setState({ contacttoassetrelationship: res.data}); this.setState({contacttoassetrelationship:
> this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.filter(contacttoassetrelationship
> => contacttoassetrelationship.assets_assetsid === this.props.match.params.assetsid)}); });

...